# Want to copy - customerid, max(price) from table items_ordered into a new table in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, select

Want to copy `customerid` and maximum price from table `items_ordered` into a new table(say A). I don't know how to copy when there is an aggregate function otherwise the query work without aggregate function column.

tried like this:

```
select customerid, max(price) into A from items_ordered group by customerid;
```

Table `items_ordered`: (http://www.sqlcourse2.com/items_ordered.html)

```
customerid  order_date  item      quantity  price
10330       30-Jun-1999 Pogo stick      1   28.00
10101       30-Jun-1999 Raft            1   58.00
10298       01-Jul-1999 Skateboard      1   33.00
10101       01-Jul-1999 Life Vest       4   125.00
10299       06-Jul-1999 Parachute       1   1250.00
10339       27-Jul-1999 Umbrella        1   4.50
10449       13-Aug-1999 Unicycle        1   180.79
10439       14-Aug-1999 Ski Poles       2   25.50
10101       18-Aug-1999 Rain Coat       1   18.30
10449       01-Sep-1999 Snow Shoes      1   45.00
10439       18-Sep-1999 Tent            1   88.00
10298       19-Sep-1999 Lantern         2   29.00
10410       28-Oct-1999 Sleeping Bag    1   89.22
10438       01-Nov-1999 Umbrella        1   6.75
10438       02-Nov-1999 Pillow          1   8.50
10298       01-Dec-1999 Helmet          1   22.00
10449       15-Dec-1999 Bicycle         1   380.50
10449       22-Dec-1999 Canoe           1   280.00
10101       30-Dec-1999 Hoola Hoop      3   14.75
10330       01-Jan-2000 Flashlight      4   28.00
10101       02-Jan-2000 Lantern         1   16.00
10299       18-Jan-2000 Inflatable M... 1   38.00
10438       18-Jan-2000 Tent            1   79.99
10413       19-Jan-2000 Lawnchair       4   32.00
10410       30-Jan-2000 Unicycle        1   192.50
10315       02-Feb-2000 Compass         1   8.00
10449       29-Feb-2000 Flashlight      1   4.50
10101       08-Mar-2000 Sleeping Bag    2   88.70
10298       18-Mar-2000 Pocket Knife    1   22.38
10449       19-Mar-2000 Canoe paddle    2   40.00
10298       01-Apr-2000 Ear Muffs       1   12.50
10330       19-Apr-2000 Shovel          1   16.75
```

result:

> An object or column name is missing or empty. For `SELECT INTO statements`, verify each column has a name. For other statements, look for empty alias names. Aliases defined as "" or [] are not allowed. Change the alias to a valid name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

//You Can Try this. You need to alias the max price to suitable name.

```
     select customerid, price=max(price) into #A from items_ordered group by customerid

select * from #A
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to give an alias to be used as the newly created column name for any expression that isn't a simple column name:

```
SELECT   customerid, MAX(price) AS max_price
INTO     a
FROM     items_ordered
GROUP BY customerid
```

Answer (score 0):

You basically have two options:

1. A `SELECT ... INTO ...` query, which creates a new table. First create a SELECT query that produces the correct result. Then, include the INTO-clause to specify a target table for the output.
2. A `INSERT ... SELECT ...` query, which requires an existing target table. The fields of the target table in the INSERT clause should match the fields in the SELECT clause.